# Cannot insert dynamic form input to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a sports database. The two tables for now are team and player. The team table has 4 columns teamId(pk) (autoinc), teamName, teamCoach and teamCity. The player table has 5 columns playerId(pk) (autoinc), playerName, playerSkill, playerPosition and teamId(fk).To insert the data I thought at first take input in teamform and then pass the result of max(teamId) query to player form so that I get the latest teamId and insert players into that teamId. Now I added dynamic forms using ajax and after verifying that it shows the array of input in console. I went to insert in the database but it does not work

connection

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$server = 'localhost';
$db = "hockey_db";

$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);

if ($con) {
    // echo "Connection Successful";
?>
    <script>
        var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
        if (alerted != 'yes') {
            alert("Connection Successful");
            localStorage.setItem('alerted', 'yes');
        }
    </script>
<?php
} else {
    // echo "Connection Unsuccessful";
    die("Connection Unsuccessful" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

teamform

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\css\styles.css">

    <title>Team Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Team Form</h1>
    <div class="myForm">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label for="teamName">Team name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="teamName" name="teamName" required>
            <label for="teamCity">City name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="teamCity" name="teamCity" required>
            <label for="teamCoach">Coach name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="teamCoach" name="teamCoach" required>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <br>
        <a href="teamList.php"><button>Team List</button></a>
    </div>
    <script>
        if (window.history.replaceState) {
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

<?php

include "connection.php";
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
    $teamName = $_POST["teamName"];
    $teamCity = $_POST["teamCity"];
    $teamCoach = $_POST["teamCoach"];


    $insertQuery = "insert into team(teamName,teamCity,teamCoach) values('$teamName','$teamCity','$teamCoach')";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $insertQuery) or die("problem inserting data into database");
    if ($res) {
?>
        <script>
            alert("Data Inserted Successfully");
        </script>
    <?php
    $playerFormId="SELECT MAX(teamId) AS teamId FROM team;";
    $playerFormRes=mysqli_query($con,$playerFormId);
    $resId=mysqli_fetch_array($playerFormRes);
    header("location:playerform.php?id={$resId["teamId"]}");
    } else {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert("Data Not Inserted");
        </script>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

playerForm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Player Form</title>
    <style>
        #submit_btn {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        table,
        td {
            border: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        td {
            border: none;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        input {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Player Form</h1>
    <div class="myForm">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="playerForm">
            <div id="show_item">
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="formtable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" id="playerName" name="playerName[]" placeholder="Player name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" id="playerSkill" name="playerSkill[]" placeholder="Player skill" required>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" id="playerPosition" name="playerPosition[]" placeholder="Player position" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="Add More" value="Add More" class="add_more_btn"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".add_more_btn").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#show_item").append(`<div class="row_append_items">
                    <table class="formtable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" id="playerName" name="playerName[]" placeholder="Player name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" id="playerSkill" name="playerSkill[]" placeholder="Player skill" required>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" id="playerPosition" name="playerPosition[]" placeholder="Player position" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="Remove" value="Remove" class="remove_btn"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>`);
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.remove_btn', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let row_item = $(this).parent().parent();
                $(row_item).remove();
            });

            $("#playerForm").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#submit_btn").val("Submitting...");
                $.ajax({
                    url:"playerformAction.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(response){
                        $("#submit_btn").val("Submit");
                        $("#playerForm")[0].reset();
                        $('.row_append_items').remove();
                        alert("data inserted successfully");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

playerformAction

```
<?php
$ids = $_GET["id"];
echo $ids;

$playerFormId = "SELECT MAX(teamId) AS teamId FROM team;";
$playerFormRes = mysqli_query($con, $playerFormId);
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($playerFormRes);

$con = new PDO(' mysql : host = localhost ; dbname = hockey_db ', ' root ', ' ');

foreach ($_POST['playerName'] as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO player (playerName,playerSkill,playerPosition,teamId) VALUES (:playerName,:playerSkill,:playerPosition,:teamId)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([
        'playerName' => $value,
        'playerSkill' => $_POST['playerSkill'][$key],
        'playerPosition' => $_POST['playerPosition'][$key],
        'teamId' => $ids,
    ]);
}
echo "Items Inserted successfully";
```

Comment: Don't add extra spaces to your connection. `' root '` is not the same as `'root'`, and `' '` is not the same as an empty string.

Comment: Please define "Does not work". Does it give an error message? Since you're attempting to submit via ajax, open up your browser's developer console, then check the console for errors and the Network tab for traffic when you attempt to submit the form.

Comment: Why are you using mysqli and PDO in the same script? For that and other reasons, this code seems a bit of a confused jumble. And what debugging have you done? There's a lot here...is it really a [mre] of your specific issue? See also [ask].

Comment: The `$sql =` and `$stmt = ` should be outside the loop. Need more details about the actual issue.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\hockey\php\playerformAction.php: but in php.ini the extension is enabled